# Loop through form input

Tags: php

I am trying to loop through form input.

My form has *1 checkbox, 1 hidden field* and *a select menu* on each row.

So in my process script, `var_dump($_POST)` gives me:

```
array(8) {
  ["remove_0"]=>
  string(2) "on"
  ["token_0"]=>
  string(12) "123"
  ["reason_0"]=>
  string(13) "Expired"
  ["remove_1"]=>
  string(2) "on"
  ["token_1"]=>
  string(13) "456"
  ["reason_1"]=>
  string(14) "Removed"
}
```

I am looking to create a PHP loop to output these in a row.

`123 | Expired`

`456 | Removed`

`...`

I had tried:

`foreach ($_POST['remove_'.$iii] as $stuff ) {`
`echo $_POST['remove_'.$iii];`
`}`

but no success.

Comment: seems a good idea, what did you try before coming to SO?

Comment: if `$_POST['remove_'.$iii]` is an array then why are you using `echo` here? where u define `$iii`

Comment: @treyBake Hey. I tried setting `$iii = 0;` then using the `foreach` but it loops through each element in the post rather than each `remove_0`, `remove_1` and so on...

Comment: I mean, I dare say I could just say if remove_0 not empty then do token_0 & reason_0 and so on but thought there would be a tidier solution to loop :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on your indexes and create a new array, then you can achieve your desired output.

**Example:**

```
<?
//your array
$array['remove_0'] = 'on';
$array['token_0'] = '123';
$array['reason_0'] = 'Expired';
$array['remove_1'] = 'on';
$array['token_1'] = '456';
$array['reason_1'] = 'Removed';

$newArray = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $groupExplode = explode("_",$key); // explode with "_"
  $newArray[$groupExplode[1]][] = $value; // save data in a new array
}

foreach ($newArray as $key => $value) {
  echo $value[1]." | ".$value[2]. "<br/>";
}
?>
```

**Result:**

```
123 | Expired
456 | Removed
```

**Side note:** but its better to optimize your `$_POST` values.

Comment: Thank you very much, @devpro. I replaced `$array` with `$_POST` which seems to do the job.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk glad to help u